# Таймер обратного отсчёта javascript

Tags: javascript

Как сделать таймер обратного отсчёта дней, часов, минут и секунд? Есть карточка -

```css
body {
  background-color: #171923;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji";
}


.card-content { 
padding: 1.5rem;
background-color: #ffffff;  
width: 22.2222%;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 32px;
height: 50%;
}

.is-flex-grow-1 { 
flex-grow: 1!important;
 }

.status-dot {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


.status-dot svg {
  font-size: 8px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.custom-card  {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #888;
    margin: 0!important;
}


.title  {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.soft-hard-cap { 
font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.soft-hard-cap span{
font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #f95192;
    margin: 0;
}

.status-dot.inprogress {
  background-color: #d1fae5;
  color: #10b981;
}

.has-text-right {
  color: #888;
}

.lockup-time p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0;
}

.liquidity-percent p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0;
}

.ant-progress-inner {
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.custom-card .content-progress {
  line-height: 1.125;
}


.soft-hard-cap p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.is-flex-grow-1 {
  flex-grow: 1!important;
}

.sub-title {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-content is-flex-grow-1">
        <div class="media is-flex is-align-items-center">
            <div class="media-content">
                <div class="is-flex is-justify-content-flex-end">
                    <div class="is-flex has-text-right is-flex-direction-column">
                        <div class="is-flex" style="text-align: right;">
                            <span class="is-flex status-dot inprogress">
                                <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M832 464h-68V240c0-70.7-57.3-128-128-128H388c-70.7 0-128 57.3-128 128v224h-68c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v384c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h640c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V496c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zM332 240c0-30.9 25.1-56 56-56h248c30.9 0 56 25.1 56 56v224H332V240zm460 600H232V536h560v304zM484 701v53c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h40c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-53a48.01 48.01 0 1 0-56 0z"></path>
                                </svg>
                                <span>Sale Live</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
            <p class="title">SUPPERCOIN</p>
            <p class="subtitle" >Fair Launch</p>
        </div>
        <div class="soft-hard-cap">
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;">Soft </p>
            <span>305 BNB</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content-progress" style="font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: var(--text-color);
        margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
    ">
            <p class="title">Progress (0.00%)</p>
            <div class="ant-progress ant-progress-line ant-progress-status-normal ant-progress-default" style="margin-top: -4px;">
                <div class="ant-progress-outer">
                    <div class="ant-progress-inner">
                        <div class="ant-progress-bg" style="width: 0%; height: 8px; background: rgba(72, 199, 116, 0.5);"></div>
                        <div class="ant-progress-success-bg" style="width: 0%; height: 8px; background-color: rgb(72, 199, 116);"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-title is-flex is-align-items-center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;display: flex;">
                <div class="is-flex-grow-1">0 BNB</div>
                <div class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right" style="text-align: right;">305 BNB</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="liquidity-percent">
            <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center" style="display: flex;">
                <p class="is-flex-grow-1">Liquidity %:</p>
                <span class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right time-text" style="text-align: right;">70%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lockup-time" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a89f9f2b;margin: 0px 0px 0.25rem;">
            <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center" style="display: flex;">
                <p class="is-flex-grow-1">Lockup Time:</p>
                <span class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right time-text" style="text-align: right;">365 days</span>
            </div></div>
        <div class="custom-card-footer">
                <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center">
                    <div class="countdown is-flex-grow-1 is-flex-direction-column">
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">Sale Starts In:</div>
                        <div class="countdown-text">
                            <strong>
                                <span>00</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span>01</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span>22</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span>06</span>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        
</body>
</html>
```

Сюда нужно внедрить таймер

Comment: А вам общее время в каком формате приходит? Общее кол-во в секундах или как объект, где расписано по-компонентно типа `{days: 1, hours: 14, ...}`?

Comment: @EzioMercer нужно, чтобы можно было в ручную вводить время, через код. Задаёшь, предположим, 5 дней и оно начинает отсчитывать. А так как объект

Comment: Куда вводить вручную? В вопросе только про таймер идёт речь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const daysCounter = document.querySelector('#days-counter');
const hoursCounter = document.querySelector('#hours-counter');
const minutesCounter = document.querySelector('#minutes-counter');
const secondsCounter = document.querySelector('#seconds-counter');

const saleStart = {days: 16, hours: 8, minutes: 4, seconds: 2};

let saleStartInSeconds = saleStart.seconds + 60 * saleStart.minutes + 3600 * saleStart.hours + 86400 * saleStart.days;

let timeout = setTimeout(function timeoutFunc() {  
  let saleStartInSecondsCopy = saleStartInSeconds;
  
  const days = Math.trunc(saleStartInSecondsCopy / 86400);
  
  daysCounter.innerHTML = `${days}`.padStart(2, '0');
  
  saleStartInSecondsCopy -= days * 86400;
  
  const hours = Math.trunc(saleStartInSecondsCopy / 3600);
  
  hoursCounter.innerHTML = `${hours}`.padStart(2, '0');
  
  saleStartInSecondsCopy -= hours * 3600;
  
  const minutes = Math.trunc(saleStartInSecondsCopy / 60);
  
  minutesCounter.innerHTML = `${minutes}`.padStart(2, '0');
  
  saleStartInSecondsCopy -= minutes * 60;
  
  secondsCounter.innerHTML = `${saleStartInSecondsCopy}`.padStart(2, '0');  
  
  --saleStartInSeconds;
  
  timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunc, 1000);
  
  if (saleStartInSeconds < 0) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #171923;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji";
}


.card-content { 
padding: 1.5rem;
background-color: #ffffff;  
width: 22.2222%;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 32px;
height: 50%;
}

.is-flex-grow-1 { 
flex-grow: 1!important;
 }

.status-dot {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


.status-dot svg {
  font-size: 8px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.custom-card  {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #888;
    margin: 0!important;
}


.title  {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.soft-hard-cap { 
font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.soft-hard-cap span{
font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #f95192;
    margin: 0;
}

.status-dot.inprogress {
  background-color: #d1fae5;
  color: #10b981;
}

.has-text-right {
  color: #888;
}

.lockup-time p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0;
}

.liquidity-percent p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0;
}

.ant-progress-inner {
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.custom-card .content-progress {
  line-height: 1.125;
}


.soft-hard-cap p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.is-flex-grow-1 {
  flex-grow: 1!important;
}

.sub-title {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-content is-flex-grow-1">
        <div class="media is-flex is-align-items-center">
            <div class="media-content">
                <div class="is-flex is-justify-content-flex-end">
                    <div class="is-flex has-text-right is-flex-direction-column">
                        <div class="is-flex" style="text-align: right;">
                            <span class="is-flex status-dot inprogress">
                                <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M832 464h-68V240c0-70.7-57.3-128-128-128H388c-70.7 0-128 57.3-128 128v224h-68c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v384c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h640c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V496c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zM332 240c0-30.9 25.1-56 56-56h248c30.9 0 56 25.1 56 56v224H332V240zm460 600H232V536h560v304zM484 701v53c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h40c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-53a48.01 48.01 0 1 0-56 0z"></path>
                                </svg>
                                <span>Sale Live</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
            <p class="title">SUPPERCOIN</p>
            <p class="subtitle" >Fair Launch</p>
        </div>
        <div class="soft-hard-cap">
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;">Soft </p>
            <span>305 BNB</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content-progress" style="font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: var(--text-color);
        margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
    ">
            <p class="title">Progress (0.00%)</p>
            <div class="ant-progress ant-progress-line ant-progress-status-normal ant-progress-default" style="margin-top: -4px;">
                <div class="ant-progress-outer">
                    <div class="ant-progress-inner">
                        <div class="ant-progress-bg" style="width: 0%; height: 8px; background: rgba(72, 199, 116, 0.5);"></div>
                        <div class="ant-progress-success-bg" style="width: 0%; height: 8px; background-color: rgb(72, 199, 116);"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-title is-flex is-align-items-center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;display: flex;">
                <div class="is-flex-grow-1">0 BNB</div>
                <div class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right" style="text-align: right;">305 BNB</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="liquidity-percent">
            <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center" style="display: flex;">
                <p class="is-flex-grow-1">Liquidity %:</p>
                <span class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right time-text" style="text-align: right;">70%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lockup-time" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a89f9f2b;margin: 0px 0px 0.25rem;">
            <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center" style="display: flex;">
                <p class="is-flex-grow-1">Lockup Time:</p>
                <span class="is-flex-grow-1 has-text-right time-text" style="text-align: right;">365 days</span>
            </div></div>
        <div class="custom-card-footer">
                <div class="is-flex is-align-items-center">
                    <div class="countdown is-flex-grow-1 is-flex-direction-column">
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">Sale Starts In:</div>
                        <div class="countdown-text">
                            <strong>
                                <span id="days-counter">00</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span id="hours-counter">00</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span id="minutes-counter">00</span>
                                <span class="dotdot">:</span>
                                <span id="seconds-counter">00</span>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот функция которая будет считывать обратный отчёт от X до 0, передаём функций время в сек и элементы гдк будут обновляться данные

```js
const dayBlock = document.querySelector('#days');
const hourBlock = document.querySelector('#hour');
const minBlock = document.querySelector('#min');
const secBlock = document.querySelector('#sec');
// Время в секундах
let time = 25005000;

window.onload = timer(time, secBlock, minBlock, hourBlock, dayBlock);

let timerController = setInterval(() => {
  if (time <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timerController);
  }
  time--;
  timer(time, secBlock, minBlock, hourBlock, dayBlock);
}, 1000);

function timer(seconds, secDiv, minDiv, hrsDiv, dayDiv) {
  let day = Math.floor(seconds / (3600 * 24));
  let hrs = Math.floor(seconds % (3600 * 24) / 3600);
  let min = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60);
  let sec = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

  secDiv.innerHTML = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;
  minDiv.innerHTML = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
  hrsDiv.innerHTML = hrs < 10 ? '0' + hrs : hrs;
  dayDiv.innerHTML = day < 10 ? '00' + day : (day < 100 ? '0' + day : day);
}
```

```css
.timer {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div id="days">000</div>
  &nbsp;
  <div id="hour">00</div>
  :
  <div id="min">00</div>
  :
  <div id="sec">00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: В конце ф-ии, где вставляете в `innerHTML`, теперь можно не писать такие проверки, вместо этого используйте [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) и [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) :) Правда IE их не понимает, но я давно уже его поддержкой не занимаюсь)) И для них есть полифилы насколько я помню, так что думаю и там можно использовать